# BigIntegers to the power of BigIntegers

Tags: java, math, primes, biginteger

I am trying to implement either the Fermat, Miller-Rabin, or AKS algorithm in Java using the BigInteger class.

I think I have the [Fermat test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test#Algorithm_and_running_time) implemented except that the BigInteger class doesn't allow taking BigIntegers to the power of BigIntegers (one can only take BigIntegers to the power of primitive ints). **Is there a way around this?**

The problematic line is denoted in my code:

```
public static boolean fermatPrimalityTest(BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger a;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int maxIterations = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        a = new BigInteger(2048, rand);

        // PROBLEM WITH a.pow(n) BECAUSE n IS NOT A BigInteger
        boolean test = ((a.pow(n)).minus(BigInteger.ONE)).equals((BigInteger.ONE).mod(n));

        if (!test)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you raise a Java BigInteger to the power of a BigInteger without doing modular arithmetic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839262/how-do-you-raise-a-java-biginteger-to-the-power-of-a-biginteger-without-doing-mod)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`BigInteger.modPow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) might be what you're looking for.  Note the "mod m" in Fermat's test.

Comment: I was looking at modPow; however, I'm not sure how to change "a^(n-1) = 1 mod n" to use modPow. I'm not too familiar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: `base.modPow(exponent, modulus)`, so in your case `a.modPow(n-1, n)`

Comment: Also note that a.pow(n), in general, can be quite ridiculously large.  You might not have enough disk space to hold that number in binary!  Doing something more sophisticated, such as modPow, is truly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One of the primality tests is built into `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`. Not sure which one, you'd have to look at the source.

Also, you can raise a number to a power by multiplying. For example: `2^100 = 2^50 * 2^50`. So pull out pieces of your `BigInteger` power and loop until you've used it up. But are you sure you don't mean to use `BigInteger.modPow()`, which takes `BigInteger`s? It looks like you are, based on your test.

Comment: I would like to build my own primality test rather than using a pre-existing one. I was looking at modPow; however, I'm not sure how to change "a^(n-1) = 1 mod n" to use modPow. I'm not too familiar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: If, for instance, it was a homework assignment, using a built-in test wouldn't cut it.  Hypothetically speaking, of course.

Comment: Ducks generally do not need a label saying "duck" on them to be identified as such.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement your own pow() method. Look at the sources of BigInteger.pow() as a starting point.

Comment: For very large integers that will be unnecessarily expensive, particularly when the algorithm only cares about the power over a particular modulus.