# Get the number of digits of a power of 2, with large exponents?

Tags: java, string, math, int, pow

I am doing the following exercise: [The number of digits of a power of 2.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5cbf1a1e31fd82000142344c). The statement is:

> What is the number of digits of a power of 2?
>
> ```
> 2 ---> 1 digit 
> 2 * 2 = 4 ---> 1 digit 
> 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 ---> 1 digit
>   2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16 ---> 2 digits
>   ... ... ... 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 1024 ---> 4 digits
> ```
>
> Then, given the exponent, what would be the number of digits of
>   that power?

I have tried the following answer:

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 
public class Power {
    public static long digit(long exp) {
    System.out.println("exp: "+exp);
    BigInteger pow = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow((int)exp);
    return String.valueOf(pow).split("").length;
    }
}
```

However it times out with big exponents like: 562078812

How could we improve this solution? Is there any fastest answer?

I have also read:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-pow-method-in-java/
- [BigInteger.pow(BigInteger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582277/biginteger-powbiginteger)
- [Infinite Loop During Calculation of Power of Big Integers Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025494/infinite-loop-during-calculation-of-power-of-big-integers-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-digits-in-2-raised-to-power-n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest answer is to use math.
The number of digits in 2^n is (nlog₁₀2)+1 .
You can achieve that by simply returning `n * Math.log10(2) + 1`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In decimal system, there will be exactly (n+1) digits in 10 power n.

- 10 power 1 has 2 digits.
- 10 power 2 has 3 digits.
- 10 power 3 has 4 digits.
- ...
- .....
- 10 power n has (n+1) digits.

The trick here is to find number of **decimal** digits in the exponent of '**2**'.

The difficult way to find the answer is to actually calculate  ***2 power n*** and then count the number of digits. However, this method requires huge computing power.

The simpler answer lies in the difference between 10 and 2.

If power of 2 raises by 1 in binary system, then digits in decimal system raise only by log 2 base 10!

For a raise of n powers in binary, the equivalent will be 
(n *log2_base_10 + 1) in decimal system.

**Working solution:**

```
public class Power {
    public static long digit(long exp) {
        return (long) (Math.ceil(exp * Math.log10(2)) + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long exp = 50000000;
        System.out.println("Number of digits in 2 power " + exp 
                            + " = " + Power.digit(50000000));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> $ javac Power.java
>   $ java Power
>
> Number of digits in 2 power 50000000 = 15051501

Answer (score 0):

Use static method like below to compute number of digits. I think this is faster way

```
static int countDigits(int n) 
{ 
    return (int)(n * Math.log10(2) + 1); 
}
```