# How to Calculate 10^5 in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am new to flex and I am struggling to know how to calculate 10^5 (10 to the power 5).

If It was a java code I would have written like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734408/how-to-find-power-of-power-of-a-number-like-2109-in-java)

But In this case, I didn't found any example on the web as well.

Any clue!

Comment: Is http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html what you're after?

Comment: @JonSkeet , Thanks It worked, **Math.pow()**

Comment: @JonSkeet should post it as an answer

Comment: @Clintm: Given that I only found it via a search, with no experience of Flex, I wasn't convinced it was correct. I'm still not sure whether that link is a genuinely useful one in itself...

Comment: @JonSkeet At least I got my solution in there, so I think this may help others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether this link is still relevant or not, but the [Adobe Flash ActionScript documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html) still has `Math.pow`:

> Computes and returns `base` to the power of `pow`.