# BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger, BigInteger)?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I'm trying to calculate a large number, which requires `BigInteger.Pow()`, but I need the exponent to also be a `BigInteger` and not `int`.

i.e.

```
BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger)
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** I came up with an answer. User [dog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301192/dog) helped me to achieve this.

```
public BigInteger Pow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent)
{
    BigInteger originalValue = value;
    while (exponent-- > 1)
        value = BigInteger.Multiply(value, originalValue);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a number that large?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582277/biginteger-powbiginteger?rq=1

Comment: I agree with @RufusL, `int` supports a maximum of ~2 billion, do you really need to raise something to the power of 2 billion?

Comment: @Matthew Yes. 2 billion isn't enough in order to calculate it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9):

Just from the aspect of general maths, this doesn't make sense. That's why it's not implemented.

Think of this example: Your `BigInteger` number is **2** and you need to potentiate it by 1024. This means that the result is a 1 KB number (2^1024). Now imagine you take `int.MaxValue`: Then, your number will consume 2 GB of memory already. Using a `BigInteger` as an exponent would yield a number beyond memory capacity!

---

If your application requires numbers in this scale, where the number itself is too large for your memory, you probably want a solution that stores the number and the exponent separately, but that's something I can only speculate about since it's not part of your question.

---

If your your issue is that your exponent variable is a `BigInteger`, you can just cast it to int:

```
BigInteger.Pow(bigInteger, (int)exponent); // exponent is BigInteger
```

Comment: And of course if he has a `BigInteger` value that just happens to be less than ~2 billion he can always cast it down to an `Int32` before passing it to `pow`, if that's his concern.

Comment: The number is too large to use int. Example of a large number to be calculated: [Googleplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googleplex)

Comment: Googlepex can not be stored in memory as a number. It would consume memory beyond imagination (10^100 bytes). What do you need those numbers for and why can't handle them "theoretically" rather than actually storing the number?

Comment: Googol is 10^100. But Googolplex is 10^10^100. Therefore, it cannot simply be calculated.

Comment: Well, you answered your own question then ;)

Comment: `The result is a 1KB number`, `Your number will consume 2 GB of memory`: not quite. They will consume 1Kb and 2 Gb (notice the lowercase b which stands for bits, not bytes). That's still a lot, but 1/8 the memory.

Answer (score 5):

Pow(2, int64.MaxValue) requires 1,152,921 terabytes just to hold the number, for a sense of scale. But here's the function anyways, in case you have a really nice computer.

```
  static BigInteger Pow(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
     BigInteger total = 1;
     while (b > int.MaxValue) {
        b -= int.MaxValue ;
        total = total * BigInteger.Pow(a, int.MaxValue);
     }
     total =  total * BigInteger.Pow(a, (int)b);
     return total;
  }
```

Comment: You're funny :D Maybe in a thousand years, someone will stumble upon this post and laugh at us having just a few gigs of RAM...

Comment: When I try to use this method, I get `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.` Can I perform the action without throwing an exception?

Comment: A computer with 1 bit of memory can store a number from 0 to 1, a computer with 100 bits of memory can store a number from 0 to (2^100)-1. The biggest number you could compute is about Pow(2,bits available). So the function above will not work if you don't have enough memory, hence the 'System.OutOfMemoryException' exception.

Comment: 1,152,921 terabytes should be enough for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, raising something to a power higher than the capacity of `int` is bad news. However, assuming you're aware of this and are just being given your exponent in the form of a `BigInteger`, you can just cast to an `int` and proceed on your merry way:

```
BigInteger.Pow(myBigInt, (int)myExponent);
```

or, even better,

```
try
{
    BigInteger.Pow(myBigInt, (int)myExponent);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    // Do error handling and stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to use the function **BigInteger.ModPow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent, BigInteger modulus)** because I needed to do a mod afterwards anyway.

The function calculates a given BigInteger to the power of another BigInteger and calculates the modulo with a third BitInteger. 
Although it will still take a good amount of CPU Power it can be evaluated because the function already knows about the modulo and therefore can save a ton of memory.

Hope this might help some with the same question.

Edit:
Is available since .Net Framework 4.0 and is in .Net Standard 1.1 and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
public BigInteger Pow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent)
{
    BigInteger originalValue = value;
    while (exponent-- > 1)
        value = BigInteger.Multiply(value, originalValue);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: And how long does it take to run this method on a number that's bigger than `long.MaxValue`?