# alogrithm for traveling throw a sequence

Tags: java

i was trying  to write a JAVA code to type these numbers

7, 87, 387, 5387, 95387, 195387, 4195387, 64195387, 464195387, 2464195387, 62464195387, 262464195387, 7262464195387, 27262464195387, 627262464195387, 5627262464195387, 75627262464195387, 575627262464195387, 4575627262464195387, 4575627262464195387

but when i wrote this code on netbeans it doesn't give me the sequence i want

```
 public class Sum30 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      double a;
   for(double i=2;i<100;i++){
      a=7;
   a=  (pow(3,a)%pow(10,i));
          System.out.println(a);
       }      

    }}
```

please tell me what is the wrong

Comment: what do you get? Wrong numbers pointing to a math error, or unexpected output or an exception?

Comment: I assume that you are experiencing the lack of precision from `double` usage, for such huge values you should use `BigInteger`. Also consider moving the declaration of `a=7` prior to the cycle - otherwise your loop makes no sense.

Comment: and yes i do exported a the class Math

Comment: but i can't  any data type except double    pow function  returns double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To over come such defects or error use `BigInteger` as it has large range and to get precise value.

Answer (score 4):

`pow(3,a)` produces *huge* numbers for big `a` values, so it will very soon (starting from `Math.pow(3, 87)`) produce values outside the range of `double` ("Infinity").

Also, your algorithm is entirely integer-based. You shouldn't use floating-point numbers for that calculation. Especially the loop index being `double` has a "smell" (even if it works in your case).

I recommend using `int` for the loop index and `BigInteger` for `a`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(7);
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        a = (BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(a.intValue()).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(i)));
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Note that `pow` takes an `int` for the exponent, so this solution has a limit, too.

In order to avoid that limit, you may want to [write your own `pow` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582440/4271479) or use the combined `modPow` operation. Since you know beforehand that the result of your exponentiation will be modulo a (*relatively* small) number, you can use the combined operation that uses that knowledge to execute the exponentiation *much* more efficiently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(7);
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        a = BigInteger.valueOf(3).modPow(a, BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(i));
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

This version doesn't have a limit apart from the available memory and the available processing time.

Answer (score 1):

You do this calculation in the loop:

```
 a=7;
 a=  (pow(3,a)%pow(10,i));
```

So pow(3,a) is always the same (2187), since a is always reset to 7. pow(10,1) quickly becomes much bigger than 2187, so the modulo becomes 2187. Your math is wrong, I think.