# How to find sum of separate digits of a number?

Tags: java, char, sum, int

I'm trying to solve Project Euler #16:

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

question looks simple but Instead of using modulus 10 I tried to solve the question like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


      long number = (long) Math.pow(2,100);

      long sum=0;

      String number2 = String.valueOf(number);

      char[] digits = number2.toCharArray();

      for (char digit : digits) {

        sum = sum + digit;
      }

      System.out.println(sum);



    }


}
```

However it gives a wrong answer, I can't see my mistake, Isn't it possible to solve this question with this way?

Comment: 2^100 won't fit into long, you need to look into BigInt types

Comment: But I cant cast `Math.pow(2,100)`to BigInteger?

Comment: yes you cant, but pow is just a multiplication after all

Comment: Aside from the storage limits of a long, you might also want to look at how you're adding your digits. As you have it, you're adding the ASCII values of each digit of the number. You should try subtracting 48 from each digit before adding it to the total to get its numeric value.

Comment: @Andrevin, better use `Character.getNumericValue()` or `Character.digit()`. ASCII arithmetic is so low-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long` cannot hold the number.  You must rewrite using a datatype that can.

See [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java) for pointers.

Comment: I tried using *BigInteger* but I can't cast it to `Math.pow(2,100)`

Comment: You cannot use `Math.pow` for this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4582277/53897