# Run a calculation with a huge base and exponent in java

Tags: java, encryption, overflow, biginteger, largenumber

I need to do a **very large calculation in a blind signature scheme** to get a blinded token. I have **tried this in java using the BigInteger class**. I believe my current code is correct as it runs but ends up throwing an exception as the number would overflow the supported range.

The calculation I initially tried shown below.

```
BigInteger blindedToken = hashedToken.multiply(randomElementDecimal.pow(formattedValue.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3))));
```

**This cannot work** as `BigInteger pow()` must take an `int` value. Therefore, [**I used my own `Helpers` class to do this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582440/2442804).

```
class Helpers { 
    public static BigInteger pow(BigInteger base, BigInteger exponent) {
          BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
          while (exponent.signum() > 0) {
            if (exponent.testBit(0)) result = result.multiply(base);
            base = base.multiply(base);
            exponent = exponent.shiftRight(1);
          }
          return result;
        }
}
```

So the updated calculation looks like this.

```
BigInteger blindedToken = Helpers.pow(randomElementDecimal, formattedValue.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3)));
blindedToken = blindedToken.multiply(hashedToken);
System.out.println(blindedToken);
```

Which worked out as

```
Z = 941180828215645688530913292077221835722091184537123007963440625299702649269*1631434789^(222347888349073615524064151195238689903425040008399562092481278391150317944919*3)
```

Z = h(Tid)*R^(public exponent * formatting value)

I have since made the numbers shorted by changing the hashed values from the result of SHA-256 to SHA-1 but I am still facing issues.

It **seems to run forever** and I assume it will overflow because **the calculation is so massive**.

I was just wondering if there was **another way around calculating this and storing the value**. **Or if this will be supported in another language like Python?**

Comment: What runs forever, what is the actual java statement that runs forever, what is the input, what is the expected output? Provide a [mcve]!

Comment: How are you planning to output the answer?  The number of digits in the answer is more than the number of atoms in the known universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to the power of that kind of number is going to take a few billion years on any hardware.

Usually, with crypto, all of this needs to go modulo something, and therein lies the rub. x^y % z, with y being some ungodly number, but z being of reasonable size, CAN be done quickly, but not with Math.pow.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCpQnxVj5h3e6sxDXD3mprx9HgZ-5bWL/view?usp=sharing) The paper I was attempting to reproduce can be found here. I have attempted to follow the calculation correctly (I could be wrong). The later equations do involve some form of modulo so I do not imagine those to be an issue. It is just the initial blinding of the token.

Comment: See also last page of that linked paper - a modulo is definitely involved. Note that if you somehow find god and ask god to calculate that in reasonable time, the resulting number is a few GB large.

Comment: I see that modulo is involved _after_ the blinded token generation, but I do not believe it is in the equation I am attempting to reproduce to get Z. I guess it is a matter of trying to reduce the size of the elements forming said equation. @rzwitserloot

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about Cryptography, your missing point is that you need a modulus. In cryptography, we mostly work on finite moduli. It seems that you are trying to RSA like blind signatures, therefore you need power on modulus.

Them, use the [modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)) of the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) Class and available since JDK1.1. This [uses](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l2495) the [modular version of the square-and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) technique, it has `O(log n)` complexity where `n` is the exponent. In each step, the intermediate values can be at most `m^2`.

```
modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m)
```

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this<sup>exponent</sup> mod m). (Unlike pow, this method permits negative exponents.)

Comment: I can indeed get this to run using the `modPow()` function. The only problem I am having is that the initial blinded token generation `(Z)` _does not_ use modulus. The future equations in the protocol _do_ use a modulus so I think this is the only issue here. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCpQnxVj5h3e6sxDXD3mprx9HgZ-5bWL/view)

Comment: The target is known, so you can use the modpow.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify how that is achieved please? I just can't seem to figure out the correct method of doing that :) @kelalaka

Comment: It is the (4) equation.