# BigIntegers for exponent (in function pow)

Tags: kotlin, biginteger, pow

Im trying to make a program where you give to BigIntegers, finds their power and returns the last digit. But im having troubles passing the bigInteger into the pow method.Is there any way ?

```
Note: I dont want to change the bigInteger to an int
```

code:

```kotlin
import java.math.BigInteger;


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(lastDigit(BigInteger("1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"),BigInteger("2037035976334486086268445688409378161051468393665936250636140449354381299763336706183397376")))
}

fun lastDigit(base: BigInteger, exponent: BigInteger): Int {
    
    var allDigits : String = base.pow(exponent).toString()
    
    return allDigits[allDigits.count()-1].toInt()
}
```

output:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is BigInteger but Int was expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `BigInteger` exponent is small enough, you can convert it to `Int` first using `BigInteger.intValue()`.

However, if you do need to use actual `BigInteger`-range exponents, you may have to think about what your computer can actually hold in memory.
Please have a look at [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582277/biginteger-powbiginteger) which I guess is a duplicate of yours (it's in Java but it's about the same API).