# most efficient way to compute f(n)^f(n) where f(n)=n^n and n has 15-20 digits

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm, time-complexity

I was asked to implement the **most efficient** program in java to compute f(n)^f(n) where f(n)=n^n and for n with large number of digits(15-20). I have figured that binary exponentiation(exponentiation by squaring) may be the most efficient for the exponentiation with a time complexity of O(log(n)), but am still unclear what the best way is to represent n's with 15-20 digits.

The person asked the question suggested implementing a `linked-list` to handle the representation and the arithmetic operations, and there's also the option of using java's built-in `BigInteger`. Which of these two are more efficient? And any suggestions on how to approach this problem, regarding the data representation, arithmetic operations, time complexity and etc.?

**Edit:** I believe the efficiency mentioned here is mostly with regards to time complexity, maybe to a lesser extend space complexity.

**Edit2:** modpow is not in the problem description and it doesn't seem to be applicable for the exponentiation problem. Also, I may have overstated the efficiency requirements, **for big integers, the only requirement is that it's "working".**

**Edit3:** Using bigInteger does not seem to make much sense at this point considering the answers and comments.

Comment: _"most efficient"_ considers many things (performance, memory usage, code size) et cetera, but I am guessing you mean performance? However, performance differs quite greatly depending on the implementation and machine. So, as with all performance questions, there will always be one answer: measure it yourself.

Comment: I don't see any reason to suppose, *a priori*, that `BigInteger` would be less efficient for your purposes than something you put together yourself.  I certainly don't see any reason to think that using a linked list would inherently provide any particular efficiency advantage.  Moreover, `BigInteger` already has a `pow(int)` method.  That's not sufficient for your purposes, but it will help.

Comment: "n has 15-20 digits" ok, let's take 10^16 as a conservative example. How many digits will f(n) have? 16*10^16. Any realistic representation of this number is unlikely to fit in your computer (that can take let's say 10^12-ish). And you still have one round of exponentiation to go. That representation is unlikely to fit in the observable universe. Unless you want some specific property of the result (e.g. what is the result modulo k), you will not reach anything useful.

Comment: `y=f(n)^f(n)` then `log(y)=f(n)*log(f(n))` which is much simple to calculate and then `y=e^log(y)`. You can also apply this method for `n^n`

Comment: Due to excessive memory requirements this cannot be implemented on current computers unless you only want the answer modulo some number. If you want it modulo some number, the math in https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch05s02.html is likely to be extremely helpful.

Comment: Calculating `(n^n)^(n^n)` is not feasible, but estimating it with schemes such as "Find k such that [10 tetrated to the k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) is closest to (n^n)^(n^n)" can be fun. Or just calculate `log10(log10((n^n)^(n^n)))`.

Comment: If you choose `n`as `10`, `n^n` will be `10,000,000,000` Repeating for the second exponent you get `10^(100,000,000,000)` So the answer for `10` will have `1` followed by `100,000,000,000` zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the exercise is for you to try them, use something like [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) to test it. Note that you're asking for `n^n^n^n` where `n` is 20 digits. The end result will very very large. 160,000 digits... or maybe I'm off by a few million in that calculation and it's *a lot* larger than that.

BigInteger's API does not have a `.pow(BigInt)` method - only `.pow(int)` and `.modPow(BigInt exponent, BigInt modulo)`. You can't unroll the power function into a for-loop that repeatedly applies a multiplication function because that would take far too long.

A basic [repeated squaring implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582277/biginteger-powbiginteger):

```
BigInteger pow(BigInteger base, BigInteger exponent) {
  BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
  while (exponent.signum() > 0) {
    if (exponent.testBit(0)) result = result.multiply(base);
    base = base.multiply(base);
    exponent = exponent.shiftRight(1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Using this to pow 2 54-bit numbers together (54-bit roughly matches '16 digits') takes hours.

Using that to calculate `n^n^n^n` probably is going to take a few trillion millenia. I don't see how linked lists are going to make this any faster.

99.99% of the time that 'calculate `a^b` where a and b are humongous numbers' comes up, is cryptography, and **always**, in that context, it's **not** `pow` that is being asked for. It's `modPow`, and the modulo is about as large as the inputs (so, a 'workable' amount of digits, i.e. less than 1024, versus the much, much larger amount of digits this is gonna take). You might wanna check with your friend if that's what they were talking about, in which case, biginteger's `modPow` is what you're looking for. It's *designed* to do this, and do it quickly.

If you ever ask the question:

"The core libraries have this function that does exactly what I want and fits the domain I need precisely. I am afraid it will be too slow; can I write a faster algorithm?"

The answer is *always*: No. For this exact case you might actually have a point - BigInteger is not written to be fast, at all, it's using decimal - not a good look. Still, 'fixing' that part is going to get you a fixed-factor speedup. For example, it makes your code 1 million times faster.

Which makes **no difference at all** if the algorithm you improved by a factor of 1 million takes a billion trillion years. Dividing that by 1 million doesn't change the truth of things one iota, which is that your algorithm is not going to finish, period. Your computer will asplode well before it ever could.

Comment: BigInteger does not seem suitable for this problem then, considering your estimation. I think the point here may be less relevant to testing but more relevant to writing the algorithm the way how I would compute it by hand, but I'm not so sure either.

Comment: The point isn't so much 'BigInteger does not work', the point is 'nothing will'. As per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696728/how-many-digits-does-nn-have), the amount of digits in `n^n^n^n` where n has 20 digits, is 2`0*n*n*n`, so, _a lot_. You need a _mathematical_ algorithm. "Maybe LinkedList" is just completely misunderstanding where to even look. Forget about computers and programming. Start thinking math. I don't think it's doable at all. Once you have that, we can talk 'how do I do this in java'.

Comment: The question is about `(n^n)^(n^n)`, not `n^n^n^n` (which is slightly ambiguous but almost-always interpreted as `n^(n^(n^n))`). Note that `(n^n)^(n^n) = n^(n*(n^n))`, which is much smaller than `n^(n^(n^n))` (but still so outrageously big that every other argument in your answer still holds, since the OP specified "n with large number of digits(15-20)")