# java Inverse BigInteger?

Tags: java

I know : p,b,g,

```
(g^(a*b)) mod p = X
```

b,p,g is BigInteger

Now I want compute : `g^a mod p`

```
{X^(b^-1)} mod p = g^(a*b*(b^-1))) mod p = g^a mod p
```

In java `BigInteger` have only  `modInverse(BigInteger m)`
 Returns a `BigInteger` whose value is `(this^-1 mod m).`

How to compute `b^-1` in java `BigInteger`?

Comment: What the hell are you talking about?

Comment: You *need* a modulus to compute `b^-1` in this sense.

Comment: In general, it's impossible, because 1/b is a BigDecimal for any BigInteger that's not equal to 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839262/how-do-you-raise-a-java-biginteger-to-the-power-of-a-biginteger-without-doing-mo

Comment: do you want the one-complement or the power? you could get the one-complement over java's builtin two-complement

Comment: Is p prime? Otherwise b^-1 is not well defined for all b I believe.

Comment: p is prime.  i dont know a, if can't compute b^-1, how do i compute g^a mod p  ? :(

Answer (score 0):

How about calling [modPow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29)?

From the docs: `Returns a BigInteger whose value is (thisexponent mod m)`. That sounds like `g^a mod p` to me.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped. In my question I don't know a. How do i compute g^a mod p

Answer (score 0):

use `modInverse` method

```
BigInteger bInverse = b.modInverse(p);
```